# Nested enumerated for loops to comprehension list

Tags: python, performance, list-comprehension, nested-loops

I'm using the `textdistance.needleman_wunsch.normalized_distance` from `textdistance` library (https://github.com/life4/textdistance). I'm using it with `cdist` from `Scipy` library to compute pair distance of sequences. But the process is very long due to a nested enumerate for loop.

Here you can find the code used in `textdistance` library that takes time, I wanted to know if you had any idea of how I could speed up the nested nested for loop, maybe using list comprehension ?

```
s1 = "sentence1"
s2 = "sentevfers2"
gap = 1


def sim_func(*elements):
    """Return True if all sequences are equal.
    """
    try:
        # for hashable elements
        return len(set(elements)) == 1
    except TypeError:
        # for unhashable elements
        for e1, e2 in zip(elements, elements[1:]):
            if e1 != e2:
                return False
        return True


dist_mat = numpy.zeros(
    (len(s1) + 1, len(s2) + 1),
    dtype=numpy.float,
)

# DP initialization
for i in range(len(s1) + 1):
    dist_mat[i, 0] = -(i * gap)

# DP initialization
for j in range(len(s2) + 1):
    dist_mat[0, j] = -(j * gap)

""" Possible enhancement with list comprehension ? """
# Needleman-Wunsch DP calculation
for i, c1 in enumerate(s1, 1):
    for j, c2 in enumerate(s2, 1):
        match = dist_mat[i - 1, j - 1] + sim_func(c1, c2)
        delete = dist_mat[i - 1, j] - gap
        insert = dist_mat[i, j - 1] - gap
        dist_mat[i, j] = max(match, delete, insert)
distance = dist_mat[dist_mat.shape[0] - 1, dist_mat.shape[1] - 1]
print(distance)
```

Comment: That nested loop doesn't accumulate a third list, so a comprehension wouldn't really be appropriate for a direct translation. You could maybe use a comprehension to create a list of `match`, `delete`, `insert` triplets then iterate over those tuples, but I can't see that being any better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is slow for several reasons:

- it is (probably) executed in CPython and written in pure Python which is a **slow interpreter not designed for this kind of numerical code**;
- `sim_func` is a **generic** way to compare various kind of elements but is also very **inefficient** (allocations, hashing, exception handling and string manipulation).

The code cannot be parallelized easily and so vectorized numpy. However, you can use Numba to speed it up. It will worth it only if the input string are quite big or this processing is executed a lot of time. If this is not the case, please use a more *appropriate programming language* (eg. C, C++, D, Rust, etc.) or a *native Python module dedicated for that*.

Here is the optimized Numba code:

```py
s1 = "sentence1"
s2 = "sentevfers2"
gap = 1  # Assume this is an integer

@njit
def NeedlemanWunschDP(dist_mat, s1, s2):
    for i in range(1, len(s1)+1):
        for j in range(1, len(s2)+1):
            match = dist_mat[i - 1, j - 1] + (s1[i-1] == s2[j-1])
            delete = dist_mat[i - 1, j] - gap
            insert = dist_mat[i, j - 1] - gap
            dist_mat[i, j] = max(match, delete, insert)

dist_mat = numpy.empty(
    (len(s1) + 1, len(s2) + 1),
    dtype=numpy.int64,
)

# DP initialization
for i in range(len(s1) + 1):
    dist_mat[i, 0] = -(i * gap)

# DP initialization
for j in range(len(s2) + 1):
    dist_mat[0, j] = -(j * gap)

# Transform the strings to fast integer arrays
tmp_s1 = numpy.array([ord(e) for e in s1], dtype=numpy.int64)
tmp_s2 = numpy.array([ord(e) for e in s2], dtype=numpy.int64)
# Needleman-Wunsch DP calculation
NeedlemanWunschDP(dist_mat, tmp_s1, tmp_s2)
distance = dist_mat[dist_mat.shape[0] - 1, dist_mat.shape[1] - 1]
print(distance)
```

The compilation time of `NeedlemanWunschDP` takes about 400 ms on my machine but the resulting code is more than *1800 times faster* on huge strings.